# iOS + WatchKit app error when authorizing HealthKit – containerAppExtensionEntitlementsWithCompletion: failed with error

Tags: swift, xcode, healthkit

**Xcode:** Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)

**MacOS:** MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65)

**Machine:** Macbook Pro 15" Mid-2015

**GitHub Repo for test project:** https://github.com/crisdenopol/healthKitTester

I am trying to create a barebones ios+watchkit app. There’s nothing else in this project but just a blank single view ios and watchkit app but I put in a healthkit authorization method in it. But when I run the app I get an error. Below is what is being outputted on the console:

2018-08-06 18:22:43.832072+0800 healthKitTest WatchKit Extension[13954:6948383] [default] containerAppExtensionEntitlementsWithCompletion: failed with error: (null) 2018-08-06 18:22:43.836490+0800 healthKitTest WatchKit Extension[13954:6948383] [default] containerAppExtensionEntitlementsWithCompletion: failed with error: (null) Authorization successful? true

Note that HealthKit is successfully authorized as indicated by "Authorization successful? true" on the console.

Comment: Errors logged to the console don't necessarily indicate your app has done anything wrong. Is anything not working, or are you just concerned about seeing that logged?

Comment: Well it does say "failed with error". So I am not sure if it's going to cause any problems later on when I add code. There must be something that's causing this error.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it without more evidence that it's causing a problem. If you're really worried about it, I'd suggest filing a bug with Apple.